# RxSwift Observable filter with casting

Tags: swift3, rx-swift

Disclaimer: i'm a half Rx newbie, so it is very possible that the idea is completely bonkers :)

I'm trying to write `ObservableType` filter, which would pass only certain type, but will pass **that type**, not the original sequence type. This is what i came up with so far:

```
extension ObservableType where Self.E: RxFilterableType {
  func filterByCast<T: RxFilterableType>(class: T.Type) -> Observable<T> {
    let retval = PublishSubject<T>()
    self.subscribe { event in
      switch event {
      case .next(let element):
        if let passed = element as? T {
          retval.onNext(passed)
        }
      case .error(let error):
        retval.onError(error)
      case .completed:
        retval.onCompleted()
      }
    }
    return retval
  }
}

func test() {
  class A: RxFilterableType {}
  class B: RxFilterableType {}

  let array: [RxFilterableType] = [A(), B()]
  let observable: Observable<RxFilterableType> = Observable.from(array)
  let observableCasted: Observable<A> = observable.filterByCast(class: A.self)
}
```

This has two problems: the lesser problem is that the inner `subscribe` disposable is not taken care of. Ideally i'd like to pass the disposal responsibility onto the return value, but i can take the disposer as parameter. I don't care.

The bigger problem is the compiler objection on the last test line:

> Using 'RxFilterableType' as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'RxFilterableType' is not supported

Which means, i'm afraid, that the compiler has not enough informations to infer what i'm trying to do, despite more-than-necessary hints i've added in desperate attempts to help the poor guy.

Comment: So you are trying to make an operator that does this? `observable.filter { $0 is A }.map { $0 as! A }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you put this in a playground configured to use RxSwift, it will work:

```
import RxSwift

extension ObservableType {
    func filterByCast<T>() -> Observable<T> {
        return self.filter { $0 is T }.map { $0 as! T }
    }
}

protocol Foo { }
struct A: Foo { }
struct B: Foo { }

let array: [Foo] = [A(), B()]
let observable = Observable.from(array)
let casted: Observable<A> = observable.filterByCast()
_ = casted.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
```

Or if you don't like specifying the type of `casted`:

```
extension ObservableType {
    func filterByCast<T>(_ class: T.Type) -> Observable<T> {
        return self.filter { $0 is T }.map { $0 as! T }
    }
}

protocol Foo { }
struct A: Foo { }
struct B: Foo { }

let array: [Foo] = [A(), B()]
let observable = Observable.from(array)
let casted = observable.filterByCast(A.self)
_ = casted.subscribe(onNext: { print($0) })
```

Requiring the class type as a parameter is a nice touch of yours. I hadn't thought of doing that.

Comment: Ok this totally works. I didn't know that `ObservableType` has its own `map` which does conveniently exactly what i need. Class type as parameter surfaced as the most convenient pattern, as the observable subscription is often a straight anonymous chain, so there is no typed observable instance which could be used for inference.